# Rspec log sql to console for filtered / tagged specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rspec, filtering

I would like to be able to see the SQL output in my console if I tag a spec specifically, or at least only for focused examples. I'm able to always show it by adding:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

but it's to verbose. I was trying to use an around condition like this with no success:

```
# log SQL to console for tests tagged with :db
config.around do |example|
  if example.metadata[:db]
    ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
  end
end
```

How can it be achieved?

Comment: you have not reverted to old logger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use `before` and `after` in my `spec_helper.rb`

```
# log SQL to console for tests tagged with :db
config.before(:each, db: true) do
  @default_logger = ActiveRecord::Base.logger
  ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
end

# log SQL to console for tests tagged with :db
config.after(:each, db: true) do
  ActiveRecord::Base.logger = @default_logger
end
```

I liked the idea of having the "ensure" possibility suggested from Paul N. and get rid of the instance variable. Paul N.'s approach raises syntax errors as the `ensure` clause can only be run inside a method.

```
def with_std_out_logger
  default_logger = ActiveRecord::Base.logger
  ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
  yield
ensure
  ActiveRecord::Base.logger = default_logger
end

config.around(:each, db: true) do |example|
  with_std_out_logger { example.run }
end
```

Comment: Great! I'm using your second solution based on Paul N. s suggestion. Thanks to the both of you!

Answer (score 1):

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.around(:example, db: true) do |example|
    old_logger = ActiveRecord::Base.logger
    ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)

    example.run

  ensure
     ActiveRecord::Base.logger = old_logger
  end
end
```